# Ошибка в добавлении элемента в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Код:**

```
import keyboard
def print_pressed_keys(e):  
    key_name_spis=[e.name]  
    key_type_spis=[e.event_type]  
    key_time_spis=[e.time]  
    a = ' '.join(key_name_spis)  
    b = ' '.join(key_type_spis)  
    c = ' '.join(str(key_time_spis))  
    return  a, b, c  
Glob_name=[]  
Glob_type=[]  
Glob_time=[]  
for Glob_ in range(len(Glob_name)+1):  
    Glob_name.append(a)  
    Glob_type.append(b)  
    Glob_time.append(c)              

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)  
keyboard.wait('Ctrl+Shift')
```

**Ошибка**: `Glob_name.append(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: У вас `a` это локальная переменная.

Comment: @entithat ,если не сложно как сделать глобальной?

Comment: @entithat спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже если сделать переменные a, b и c глобальными, в тот момент когда вы обращаетесь к ним внутри цикла функция `print_pressed_keys` еще не вызвана ни одного раза, поэтому в этих переменных будет пусто (фактически в этот момент они еще не будут существовать). Да и цикл не выполнится ни одного раза, потому что переменная `Glob_name` содержит пустой список.

Нужно добавлять значения в списки внутри самой функции:

```
import keyboard

Glob_name=[]  
Glob_type=[]  
Glob_time=[]  

def print_pressed_keys(e):  
    key_name_spis=[e.name]  
    key_type_spis=[e.event_type]  
    key_time_spis=[e.time]
    a = ' '.join(key_name_spis)  
    b = ' '.join(key_type_spis)  
    c = ' '.join(str(key_time_spis))  
    print(a, b, c)
    Glob_name.append(a)  
    Glob_type.append(b)  
    Glob_time.append(c)   

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)  
keyboard.wait('Ctrl+Shift') 

print(Glob_name)
print(Glob_type)
print(Glob_time)
```